# Index error, delete row from array if column has a value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a array 'x' with four columns.

For each row if the 4th column has a value of 1 then I want to delete that entire row:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3,0],[11,2,3,24],[1,22,3,1],[1,22,3,1], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,1]])
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    if x[i][4]==0:
        x=np.delete(x, i,0)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 2, in 
>           if x[i][4]==0:
>       IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: As a side note, with numpy arrays, you usually want to do `x[i, 4]`, not `x[i][4]`. The first version accesses the element directly, instead of accessing the row, then asking it for the element, so it can be more efficient—but, more importantly, it's more flexible when you start doing fancier stuff.

Comment: Also, `len(x)` is an odd thing to do. It does work, but if you want the size of a particular axis, ask for the size of that axis, rather than asking for the length of the array treated as a sequence of rows.

Comment: If you ever want the last item (column or row or whatever) you don't need to count the rows and use that number: instead count from the end.  The last item if 4 items is either `x[3]` or `x[-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html):

```
>>> x[x[:,3] != 1]
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  0],
       [11,  2,  3, 24],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8]])
```

Comment: @West1234 In case it's not clear, this is just showing only the rows where column `3` is not equal to `1`.  It doesn't remove them from the array, so later `x` will still have all the rows.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to reference the fourth column with [4], but since it's zero based it's actually [3]

Answer (score 0):

The index of a list starts from `0`. So, since there are 4 elements, the  indexes are :`0,1,2,3`. So, if you have to check the 4th element, use index 3.

```
if x[i][3]==0:
     pass
```

This will work