# How could I remove the rows of an array if one of the elements of the row does not satisfy a condition?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to remove the rows of an array when the elements of third column of the array are less than specific amount. For example:

```
a=np.array([[2331.13,1944.88,23.1379,7,3.18339,0.482105],
[8168.44,1904.70,19.5025,265,4.12642,0.0376510],
[7389.36,1983.97,14.3581,3937,6.04109,0.713416],
[1765.18,1944.29,22.5495,35,2.30717,0.794432],
[2319.33,1946.68,22.4300,25,3.63676,0.0210690],
[785.666,2090.69,14.7940,1095,2.52823,0.999842],
[4071.24,2186.92,22.6616,31,2.79309,0.0312501],
[7082.51,2191.69,23.0122,19,2.53166,0.687001]])
```

I would like to remove rows which satisfy the following condition:

```
a[:,2]<15.0
```

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Index error, delete row from array if column has a value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18858396/1730674)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
a[a[:,2]>=15.0, :]
```

Note the inversion of `a[:,2]<15.0` to `a[:,2]>=15.0`, so that you're describing rows that you want to *keep* rather than *remove*.

If inverting your condition isn't as simple as that, you could also use `~`:

```
a[~(a[:,2]<15.0), :]
```

Comment: I tend to use the tilde instead:`a[~(a[:,2] < 15), :]`.

Comment: Note this does not delete the rows from the array, it simply shows only the other rows.  To do that you must do something like this: `a = a[a[:,2]>=15]`, or `a = np.delete(a, np.where(a[:,2]<15, 0)`. (Also, there is no need for the trailing `:`)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straight forward way to remove rows or columns is to use `np.delete`

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> a[:,2]
array([ 2,  6, 10, 14])
>>> to_remove = a[:,2] < 7
>>> to_remove
array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> new_a = np.delete(a, to_remove, axis=0)
>>> new_a
array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

In one line:

```
new_a = np.delete(a, a[:,2] < 7, axis=0)
```