# Remove rows from array if values in a column are greater than a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1.1,5,100],[2.4,6,200],[3.3,7,300],[4.1,8,400],[4.9,9,500],[5.5,10,600],[6,5],700,[6.5,12,800],[7.2,20,900],[8,20,1000]])
b=np.max(a[:,0])#finds maximum value in 1st column(index=0)
if b > 5:
   Do something
```

I want the code to identify the first row in column 1 of the array that has a value greater than 5 and then delete the rows after that.  This should only happen if the maximum value in column 1 is greater than 5. The resultant array, c, should look like this:

```
c=np.array([[1.1,5,100],[2.4,6,200],[3.3,7,300],[4.1,8,400],[4.9,9,500]])
```

Comment: And what is your problem? We don't do homework assignments here

Answer (score 3):

Solution found:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1.1,5,100],[2.4,6,200],[3.3,7,300],[4.1,8,400],[4.9,9,500],[5.5,10,600],[6,5],700,[6.5,12,800],[7.2,20,900],[8,20,1000]])
b=np.max(a[:,0])#finds maximum value in 1st column(index=0)
if b > 5:
    c=a[a[:,0]<=5,:]
```

I found the solution on:

[How could I remove the rows of an array if one of the elements of the row does not satisfy a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010990/how-could-i-remove-the-rows-of-an-array-if-one-of-the-elements-of-the-row-does-n)