# removing an entire row with conditions on a column

Tags: python, numpy

Following the question and solution posted here:

[How could I remove the rows of an array if one of the elements of the row does not satisfy a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010990/how-could-i-remove-the-rows-of-an-array-if-one-of-the-elements-of-the-row-does-n)

I like to ask how to delete a row with a combined operator condition on a column value. In short, I like to delete all the rows whose 3rd column values are not between 7 and 15.

```
print (data[:,2])
to_remove = data[:,2] < 7 and  data[:,2] >= 15
```

The above line is not allowed and it throws a value error.

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
to_remove = (data[:,2] < 7) | (data[:,2] > 14)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now to my real problem. I have column values as floats=2.88168034e+01. Therefore, `to_remove = (data[:,2] < 20.) | (data[:,2] > 19.)` should eliminate all the entries from the array, but I see the warning as `fetchRuns.py:21: FutureWarning: in the future insert will treat boolean arrays and array-likes as boolean index instead of casting it to integer
  new_data = np.delete(data, to_remove, axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this :

```
   result = []
   for row in arr:  # loop over the rows
      if row[2] > 7 and row[2] < 15: # this is the condition you need 
         result.append(row) # store the rows which third column is between 7 and 15 in a new array

   print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

to_remove = (data[:,2] < 7) |  (data[:,2] >= 15)